# How can I install fonts to NetBeans in the properties?

Tags: java, netbeans, fonts

I would like to know how I can install new sources to the fonts properties in netbeans

Here I leave an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH1HG.jpg

Comment: Probably just install it in the system and netbeans will use it. Also, that's not a programming question.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to use this page
and no, when installing it on the system it does not detect it, so I would like to know if there is any way to install it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit netbeans.conf file which is located in `C:\Program Files\NetBeans8.2\etc\netbeans.conf`

Search for `netbeans_default_options` in `netbeans.conf` file

Add `-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on` to the end of the `netbeans_default_options`

[image]

Now you can use system fonts in Netbeans. So change your font in `Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try:

```
     Tools > Options > Fonts & Colours > Syntax
            Category: default
            Font: ([...]) > Select Font
```

2. Or:

Adding them to the `.fonts/ directory`